# Rails Prawn - Bordered long text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have a long text which overflows to several PDF pages. I'd like to border this text. I've tried following code:

```
    column_box([0, cursor], :columns => 1, :width => bounds.width) do
      stroke_color "000000"
      stroke_bounds
      text(budget.additional_info, {size: 20})
    end
```

But it doesn't work. It just prints a border on top of text on first page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. You must put the `stroke_bounds` at end of `column_box`

```
column_box([0, cursor], :columns => 1, :width => bounds.width) do
  text(budget.additional_info, {size: 20})
  stroke_color "000000"
  stroke_bounds
end
```

Sorry my bad english. Grettings!